# C open files in a loop with iterating number

Tags: c, file, loops, fopen

I want to open a number of files in that way that I can define a number of files to open. I tried a simple example:

```
numfiles = 2; //defined number of files

char *FILENAME1 = "File1.synt";
char *FILENAME2 = "File2.synt";

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

int nf=1; //iterator
for (nf=1;nf<=numfiles;nf++){

    char str[15];
    sprintf(str, "%d", nf);

    printf("%s\n",concat("FILENAME",str)); // just to test concat, results in: FILENAME1

    Fileid = fopen(concat("FILENAME",str),"r");

    //dosomething()

    close(Fileid)

    }
```

but I cant open the files?!

What went wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to open the literal file "FILENAME1", not what's at the variable.  Why aren't the file names in an array?

Comment: Please submit code that would actually compile. It looks like you have a for loop that's not in a function, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code builds the 'FILENAME1' string and therefore try to open the file with this name. Your FILENAME1 variable that contains 'File1.synt' is not used.
QuickFix:
replace

```
Fileid = fopen(concat("FILENAME",str),"r");
```

by

```
char filename[30];
sprintf(filename, "File%d.synt", nf);
Fileid = fopen(filename ,"r");
```

This also removes your 'concat' method which was leaking memory.

Comment: Your sprintf is missing an argument!